# Creating objects from a column and assigning values from another in R

Tags: r

I want to read a data like -

```
Name, Value
A,20
B,23
C, Stupid
D, IDIOT
```

And then I want to create several objects from col Name with values from col Value to the effect that -

```
A <- 20
C <- Stupid
```

and so on.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try `list2env(setNames(as.list(data$Value), data$Name), globalenv())`

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying for loop with eval(mydata$Name[I]) <- mydata$Value[I], but it's not working, may I ask why not? I tried left side in quotes and get function as well, but nothing worked.

Comment: Akanksha, it's because the left hand side gets fully evaluated, so instead of storing to a name, you are trying to store to the string in the name column, which doesn't make any sense. Check out `?assign` - but you should stay away from assigning variables like this. It's much better, handier and safer to use lists.

Comment: Many thanks Allan. I tried assign as well, but even that created issues. The reason I want to go like this is because I am storing a bunch of constants to be used in specific cases in a cab and after reading the CSV file, I wanted to retrieve those constants. Yours is a very elegant solution. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to do this (though it would make more sense to keep the objects in a list), you can do

```r
list2env(setNames(as.list(data$Value), data$Name), globalenv())
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

ls()
#> [1] "A"    "B"    "C"    "D"    "data"
```

---

**Data**

```r
data <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Value = c("20", 
"23", "Stupid", "IDIOT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Name = list("A", "B", "C", "D")
Value = list(20, 23, "enthusiastic", "beginner")
mapply(assign, Name, Value, MoreArgs=list(envir=parent.frame()))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `assign` with a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(data))) assign(data$Name[i], data$Value[i])
```

---

Or with `zeallot`

```
library(zeallot)
c(A, B, C, D) %<-% data$Value
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Value = c("20", 
"23", "Stupid", "IDIOT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
list2env(type.convert(setNames(as.list(df$Value), df$Name), as.is = TRUE),.GlobalEnv)
```